# Activity keep showing the same data of first run

Tags: android

I have 3 activities , A and B is are a  list activities , C is result viewer that get id's from A  OR B and show the details .

The problem is when i install and run the application A OR B  , i click on any items to call C by intent , and the correct data is shown with no problem , and when i go back and select another item from A OR B , the same first result is shown , even if i close the application and reopen it , this value is stuck , it's suppose to show the new selection.

any idea please

Comment: finish older activity on new Intent

Comment: are you sure ? in which activity i need to do that and a small example pls im a beginner

Comment: Post your code, how you start Activity C and code how your show data on Activity C

Comment: use finish(); just after you fire intent in all a,b,c activities

Comment: i tried to use finish() , On C activity only getting data from intent , i tried to finish it when clicking back , or onPause() and it didnt work , the same first values keep shwoing on C